# What does "OP" mean?

Tags: discussion

I've seen that word ('OP') on "Math.SE" a couple of times and, I'm actually not sure about it's meaning. Is it a jargon or term for example? Could someone explain it simply, please?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW "dup" ("dupe"?) is duplicate post.

Comment: :D That "dupe" sounds strange but, thanks for the information you have given. :)

Comment: WOW, "OP" is used incorrectly *so many* times.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**OP** = **O**​riginal **P**​ost(er)

It refers to either the original post (which may be the original *question* or the original *answer* on which a comment is placed) or the author of said post.

See also [this Meta.SO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, Willie.

Comment: And another similar thread here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/cfv-instant-lookup-for-acronyms-needed-on-main-and-meta

Comment: @Martin: ah thanks! I was looking for that post, but my search-fu wasn't good enough and I have the MSO one bookmarked.